# Functional ubuntu-touch lock screen

Tags: ubuntu-touch, security, development

Is a functional lock screen (e.g. pin or password) for Ubuntu Touch being developed? The nearest thing I could find was a design mockup from July with a hardcoded password http://design.canonical.com/2013/07/unlocking-the-phone/

The os seems to be shaping up nicely and I'd love to be able to test it in the real world but I can't until it has this feature.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the developer working on it!

It is being developed, but it's a lot harder than it looks.  The current lock screen is built into the shell.  But to be a proper lock screen, we need to separate it out to be a proper LightDM greeter that runs as a different user and has to share a bunch of information with the user session.

Hopefully will have something working by 14.04.

Comment: any updates? :) [and is there is a version for desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/587570/how-to-install-ubuntu-touch-lock-screen-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: It works!  The phone version has a functioning lockscreen.The code isn't separated out in a desktop-friendly way yet.  But that's being actively worked on.

Answer (score 2):

It's in: Settings → Security → Safety after locking. The options are: 4 digits, finger movement, or password.

(Ubuntu 14.10 r179)